# How to identify outliers in a ratio X/Y where Y is a frequency, and thus implies a confidence?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose every day you test a group of people for some disease. You measure the percent of people who tested positive for the disease, call this *PositiveRate*.

Now suppose on the recent day, the *PositiveRate* was noticeably high or low, but you've only tested a small number of people. What strategy(s) might you use to classify this high or low *PositiveRate* as an outlier?

## Example

To make this more concrete, here's some data

```
daily <- data.frame(
  PeopleTested = c(100, 80, 130, 55, 127, 91),
  HasDisease = c(   10,  7,  10,  3,  15,  7)
)
daily$PositiveRate <- daily$HasDisease / daily$PeopleTested

daily
  PeopleTested HasDisease PositiveRate
1          100         10   0.10000000
2           80          7   0.08750000
3          130         10   0.07692308
4           55          3   0.05454545
5          127         15   0.11811024
6           91          7   0.07692308
```

Now suppose the next day you test 25 people for the disease and 4 of them test positive ==> $PositiveRate = 0.16$. Is this an outlier?

## Inefficient Solution

An inefficient solution I can think of would be to do a simulation, whereby I randomly sample 25 people from my dataset, measure the *PositiveRate*, and then repeat this process hundreds of times until I have a distribution from which I can estimate $P(X > 0.16 | k = 25)$. Unfortunately this is slow, and it requires you have the individual case data, which I do not.

Comment: Why are you assuming X follows a normal distribution when it is based on data which clearly isn't normally distributed? I.e. it is a percentage and clearly has different restrictions on its support.

Comment: @DaleC thanks for the feedback. I've rewritten my question. Let me know if you have other suggestions, or advice on my problem.

Comment: @Xi'an I've re-written my question. Please let me know if you think this is better, or if you have another suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call Day 6 an outlier per se. I would just say that it has a higher standard error and thus lower confidence due to lower sample size. With that in mind you can think of a threshold on standard error $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be addressed using a beta-binomial model? You could have a predictor that code for possible changes in the underlying (unknown) fraction of people with the disease in the population on the next day. This would give you a p-value, essentially telling you the probability of observing that data (on the next day) under the null hypothesis that the fraction of people with disease in the population has not changed.

Using your example data:

```
daily <- data.frame(
  PeopleTested = c(100, 80, 130, 55, 127, 91, 25),
  HasDisease = c(   10,  7,  10,  3,  15,  7 , 4),
  nextDay =    c(    0,  0,   0,  0,   0,  0 , 1)
)

library(aod)
m1 <- betabin(cbind(HasDisease, PeopleTested - HasDisease) ~ nextDay, ~ 1, 
               data = daily, phi.ini=1e-8)
```

Based on this model it seems that the 'next day' should not be considered different from the previous six days ($p\approx 0.23$)

```
> summary(m1)@Coef
             Estimate Std. Error   z value Pr(> |z|)
(Intercept) -2.323521  0.1447944 -16.04703  0.000000
nextDay      0.665071  0.5585877   1.19063  0.233799
```